# c# regex to get the index of an array in a string variable

Tags: c#, regex

im just starting to work with regex. im just wondering if someone can help me build a regex to detect or get the index in a string variable for example i have this

```
var TestString = "TestArray[1]";
```

i want to be able to get the index in the TestString variable which will be = "1";

Comment: Have you tried something already? Do you _need_ to use regex?

Comment: In general, parsing C# code with a Regex will lead to misery.  It works here because the specification you have (look for an integer between square brackets) is so simple.  It won't take long to grow way outside of regex's capabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a named variable. The following pattern finds all digits after the open square bracket

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string TestString = "TestArray[1]";
            string pattern = @"\[(?'index'\d+)";
            Match match = Regex.Match(TestString, pattern);
            string index = match.Groups["index"].Value;
        }

  

    }
}
```